# Do I need to add the preposition 'of' in this context?

Tags: prepositions

> *My friend*: I sent you the the lecture notes.
>
> *I*: I'm not sure if all (**of**?) the 3 topics are there.

Should I add the preposition '**of**' in this sentence?

Comment: I'd discard the unnecessary *article* as well - *I'm not sure **if all 3 topics** are there*.

Answer (score 2):

No, both *all* and *all of* are correct (although usage of *all of* has been growing lately).
However, in your particular example, I would remove *the*, so the phrase looks like this:

> I'm not sure if all 3 topics are there. 
>   
> OR
>   I'm not sure if all of the 3 topics are there.